# message history list returning messages with labels that do not match query/request

Tags: gmail-api

I am attempting to use the history list API to retrieve the list of INBOX messages.  The messages that are being returned do not have the 'INBOX' label set.

Here is the URL of my request:

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/history?labelId=INBOX&startHistoryId=37985130&maxResults=10

The first message returned in the messagesAdded section of the response has label ids of:
[DRAFT, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

I specified 'labelId=INBOX' in the request, so why is this message included in the response if it does not have the 'INBOX' label?  I did verify 'INBOX' is a valid label id for this user, as I would expect it to be and it is a type=system label.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762211/gmail-api-history-request-returning-drafts) where the answer was to specify the labelId in the request.  I am doing that, but still getting 'DRAFT' messages.  Is the filter broken or am I using it incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this instead:

Use [messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) and use the "in:INBOX" in the "`q`" property. It should return the messages from the Inbox only. Other available filters for the '`q`' property are found in [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).